# TouchableHighlight is not disabled

Tags: react-native

Setting disabled property of `TouchableHighlight` to `{!isFormValid()}` does not disable it if the form is invalid.

I'm using [react-native-form-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-form-validator) for this:

Below is snippet of the code:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]} 
                        onPress={this._onSubmit}
                        disabled={!this.state.isValid}>
      <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

The `_isValid` function is below:

```
 export default class LoginScreen extends ValidationComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isValid: false,
      email   : '',
      password: '',
    }
  }

  _isValid = () => {
    this.setState(this.isValid,this.isFormValid());
  }
```

Thanks,
Firas

Comment: Note: I never see the alert. so not sure if _isValid runs at all.

Answer (score 0):

**First issue**
is how you `setState` on your component ... `setState` function takes an `object` of your newly changed fields.

```
 _isValid = () => {
    const isValid = this.isFormValid();
    this.setState({ isValid: isValid }); // < Look at this
  }
```

**Second Issue**
In order to get an immediate update for your button state (disabled-enabled) .. you need to execute `this.validate(...)` on event onBlur of each textInput field, and change the state of your form accordingly ... calling `setState` will force your component to be re-rendered, and hence the state of your `TouchableHighlight` button will be updated accordingly.

```
onBlur = () => {
this.validate(...);

const isValid = this.isFormValid();
this.setState({ isValid: isValid });
};
```

**Suggestion**

I'd suggest to use [redux-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-form) or [formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik) for better handling of **Field-Level-Validation** or **Blur-Validation**

Comment: Hi Hend, what is calling _isValid? I set it similar to what you are suggesting:
_isValid = () => {
    this.setState(this.isValid,this.isFormValid());
  }

and I set isValid in state to false but it is always disabled.

Comment: Hi ... plz share your code ... it would be more helpful

Comment: I mean share your code ... where you call _isValid() function ... in which event in your form ... and maybe share _isValid() function itself

Comment: I updated the question with my code changes. I am trying to see where I can call _isValid function.

Comment: We usually call isValid on form submit **OR** onBlur of a specific textInput field ..

I'm trying to point out to some issues in your code that prevent it from running ... but if you ask me, I would **highly recommend** using third party library for handling forms and form-validation .. it will be robust, well-teste, production-ready and easy to integrate to your app like redux-form for formik

Comment: I am using react-native-form-validator.

Comment: Alright ... as per documentation ... you need to call `this.validate(...)` function on button press in order to get a value from `this.isFormValid()` ...

Comment: Thanks Hend. I removed disabled for now. I may revisit it again later but I don't want to spend much more time on it.